# How Do I Get WxWidgets setup.h after I install all the .debs on Debian?

Tags: c++, debian, wxwidgets

Problem first, then details:
I copied a hello-world program from the wxwidgets tutorials and tried to compile it from the command line like this:

```
g++ -o h wxhello.cpp -I/usr/include/wx-3.0
```

The compile terminated quickly because it could not find "wx/setup.h". I researched this apparently EXTREMELY COMMON PROBLEM and learned that there is supposed to be a second include path, pointing to the place where the individual setup.h that suits my situation can be found. So I tried:

```
find /usr/include/wx-3.0 -name "setup.h"
```

And the output was nothing.

So I installed wxWidgets by marking libwxgtk3.0-dev in Synaptic and allowing all the dependencies to be installed (something like 40 packages in all because I just set this thing up).

How do I get my program to compile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have `wx-config --cxxflags --libs` in your command line enclosed in back-ticks like this

```
 g++ -o h wxhello.cpp `wx-config --cxxflags --libs`
```

This is not the solution on Windows, but it should work on any Linux.

This is not documented in a searchable fashion as far as I can tell.

Comment: You should use `--cxxflags` (C++ compiler flags) and not `--cppflags` (C preprocessor flags) option. Often they return the same thing, but not always. This is documented in `docs/gtk/install.txt`.